# Вращение фигуры в openGL относительно заданной точки

Tags: c++, opengl

Можно ли задать точку вращения для фигуры в openGl? Используя glRotatef() вращается вся плоскость относительно центра. Для примера: мне нужно вращать квадрат с центром в его правом верхнем углу. Как это реализовать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
glTranslate (X, Y, Z);
glRotated (...);
glTranslate (-X, -Y, -Z);
```

X,Y,Z - координаты точки относительно которой нужно вращение